# Setting Minute and Second component of Timestamp field to 0

Tags: sql, database, timestamp, teradata, type-conversion

I have a requirement such that if I enter a timestamp(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) say

> 2015-04-05 16:45:12

I need it converted to

> 2015-04-05 16:00:00

Is there an elegant way to do this in Teradata rather than extracting hour and then casting it with date?

Comment: Use `SUBSTR` to get the string till `2015-04-05 16:` and then concatenate `00:00` to it. If you want, convert this back to timestamp, so now you would have the minutes and seconds set to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of casting from/to a string two times it's probably more efficient to substract intervals:

```
ts - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) * INTERVAL '01' MINUTE)
   - (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) * INTERVAL '01' SECOND)
```

If this is to much code simply put it in a SQL UDF.

Comment: I tried this, but the thing is intervals need to be some kind of character, whereas i would need to remove whatever minute or second that has come in. Using variable here doesn't work, even the varchar kind, I tried that.

Comment: This works as-is if `ts` is a timestamp, did you try it?

Comment: I did, but where you are using '01', i need to put variable. It doesn't work then

Comment: What other variable do you need? `'01' is a constant, but it's multiplied by the minute/second of the supplied timestamp. The result is a timestamp with minutes and seconds set to zero. This is exactly what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extract the **substr** you want to retain the values, and then **concatenate** the zeros for minutes and seconds.

For example,

```
SELECT concat(substr('2015-04-05 16:45:12', 1, 14), '00:00');
```

If you want, you could convert this back to **timestamp**, thus you will have the new timestamp value with the **minutes and seconds** value set to zero.

Comment: Thank you , I absolutely forgot about SubStr() :)